# Whitespace in Sublime Text 3

Tags: sublime-text-3

When I pressed tab in ST3 it displays a white box representing the tab.  Can anyone tell me how to disable seeing this white box?

Comment: Is it just showing for tabs or something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10354857/sublimetext-encloses-lines-in-white-rectangles

Comment: Is that just white background?

Comment: What do you mean by 'white box'?